# Searching documents where guid is in collection

Tags: c#, mongodb, norm

I'm trying out several MongoDB drivers for C#. At the moment NoRM is up on the list.

I have a query which needs to Find all documents where some LocationId is in a collection of Guids.
Some code to clarify what I want to do:

```
private IQueryable<T> QueryLocationId<T>(IEnumerable<Guid> shouldBeIn)
{
    var result = provider.DB.GetCollection<T>().Find(new { LocationId = Q.In(shouldBeIn) });
    return result.AsQueryable();
}
```

The thing is, the query isn't returning any results.
When I'm debugging through the code, I see the Find() without the In query does return all Location items. I also know for a fact a lot of the items have LocationIds which exist in the `shouldBeIn` collection.

I think the problem is the fact that I'm using Guids over here and MongoDB doesn't understand them that well. When I was using the official MongoDB driver I had to convert the Guids to  `BsonBinaryData`. Something like that probably needs to happen again, but I can't find any documentation/posts on this matter.

Someone else got a clue on how/if I need to convert the Guids?

**Note**: I'm not able to change the Guids to some other type.

Comment: Norm was a great driver, but it hasn't been supported in a very, very long time. (https://github.com/atheken/NoRM).

If this is a new project, I'd suggest moving to MongoDB's official driver.

Comment: Also, Guids in the official driver are converted to BsonBinaryData automatically, so you shouldn't need to do anything.